# Does load user profile require an app pool restart in IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

Can anybody help me understand if changing the Load user profile on IIS 7 to 'True' requires an app pool restart ? . I find after each deployment it reverts it back to the default state

Answer (score 1):

Any changes you make to the AppPool configuration automatically restarts the AppPool after you exit.